# MapReduce: java.lang.ClassCastException: class nyc311.NYC311_Writable at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Here's my basic MapReduce Program:
I am trying to create a Writable Object to save the data i.e. NYC311_Writable class and am receiving a java.lang.ClassCastException:
Any suggestions please?

Here's the error:

```
17/04/11 14:54:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
17/04/11 14:54:05 WARN mapred.MapTask: Unable to initialize MapOutputCollector org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
java.lang.ClassCastException: class nyc311.NYC311_Writable
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getOutputKeyComparator(JobConf.java:887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.init(MapTask.java:1004)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.access$100(MapTask.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:770)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Main Class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package nyc311;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

/**
 *
 * @author dhaval
 */
public class NYC311 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     * @throws java.lang.InterruptedException
     * @throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration(); 
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "NYC311");
        job.setJarByClass(NYC311.class);

        job.setMapperClass(NYC311_Mapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(NYC311_Writable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setReducerClass(NYC311_Reducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(NYC311_Writable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0: 1);
       }

}
```

Writable Object Class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package nyc311;

import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author dhaval
 */
public class NYC311_Writable implements Writable{

    private String Incident_Zip;


    public NYC311_Writable() {
    }

    public NYC311_Writable(String Incident_Zip) {
        this.Incident_Zip = Incident_Zip;
    }

    public String getIncident_Zip() {
        return Incident_Zip;
    }

    public void setIncident_Zip(String Incident_Zip) {
        this.Incident_Zip = Incident_Zip;
    }


    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput d) throws IOException {
        WritableUtils.writeString(d,Incident_Zip);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput di) throws IOException {
        Incident_Zip = WritableUtils.readString(di);

    }

    public static NYC311_Writable read(DataInput in) throws IOException {
         NYC311_Writable w = new NYC311_Writable();
         w.readFields(in);
         return w;
       }

}
```

Mapper:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package nyc311;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

/**
 *
 * @author dhaval
 */
public class NYC311_Mapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, NYC311_Writable, IntWritable>{

       private IntWritable count = new IntWritable(1);
       private Text zip = new Text();

    @Override
    protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String[] line = value.toString().split(",");    

        if (line[8].matches(".*[a-z].*")) { 

        }
        else{        

            NYC311_Writable nyc_data = new NYC311_Writable();

            nyc_data.setIncident_Zip(line[8]);
            context.write(nyc_data, count);       

        }

    }

}
```

Reducer:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package nyc311;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

/**
 *
 * @author dhaval
 */
public class NYC311_Reducer extends Reducer<NYC311_Writable, IntWritable, NYC311_Writable, IntWritable>{

    private IntWritable count = new IntWritable();

    @Override
    protected void reduce(NYC311_Writable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    int sum = 0;

    for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
    }

    count.set(sum);
    context.write(key, count);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you list down the commands you used for running this jar file?

Comment: hadoop jar /home/dhaval/NetBeansProjects/NYC311/dist/NYC311.jar /NY311_2011 /Y_NY311_2011_Out                                     

/NY311_2011 - is my csv input file
/Y_NY311_2011_Out - output file

Comment: I think you are missing the Comparable and here is the blog to guide you http://hadooptutorial.info/creating-custom-hadoop-writable-data-type/

Comment: Is it necessary to use WritableComparable? I don't wish to do the secondary sorting for now.

Comment: The program works when I used WritableComparable - Thank you soo much for your help.
But I am still not clear why did it fail when I use only Writable.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this but since Hadoop does Sorting and partitioning for key so it has to have Comparable somewhere and that's why it needs WriteableComparable and not just Writeable. But if you were writing this to hdfs from reducer or mapper I think that would have worked

Comment: Keys in MapReduce have to be Comparable, its a requirement. Without it Hadoop would have no way of determining how to group keys going into the Reduce phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the Comparable and here is the blog to guide you [hadooptutorial.info/creating-custom-hadoop-writable-data-typ‌​e](http://hadooptutorial.info/creating-custom-hadoop-writable-data-typ%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Be)